# Can I use more than one selection criteria with apply-templates?

Tags: xslt-1.0

Here is a snippet of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AssignmentHistory Version="171804">
    <W20170828>
        <StudentItems>
            <Item>
                <Name Counsel="13" NextCounsel="0" Completed="1">Name 1</Name>
                <Type>Bible Reading (Main)</Type>
                <Description>Bible Reading</Description>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name Counsel="50" NextCounsel="0" Completed="1">Name 2</Name>
                <Type>#1 Student (Main)</Type>
                <Description>Initial Call</Description>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name>Name A</Name>
                <Type>Assistant</Type>
                <Description>Initial Call</Description>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name Counsel="50" NextCounsel="0" Completed="1">Name 3</Name>
                <Type>#2 Student (Main)</Type>
                <Description>Return Visit</Description>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name>Name B</Name>
                <Type>Assistant</Type>
                <Description>Return Visit</Description>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name Counsel="33" NextCounsel="0" Completed="1">Name 4</Name>
                <Type>#3 Student (Main)</Type>
                <Description>Bible Study</Description>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Name>Name C</Name>
                <Type>Assistant</Type>
                <Description>Bible Study</Description>
            </Item>
        </StudentItems>
    </W20170828>
</AssignmentHistory>
```

Here is the XSL script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

  <xsl:variable name="PubDB" select="document('MSA_PublisherDatabase.XML')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="History" select="document('AssignHistory.XML')"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Students - Full History Report</title>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Custom Publisher Report.css"/>-->
      </head>
      <body>
        <table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher">
            <xsl:sort select="msa:Name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msa:Publisher">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="border: 1px solid #000000">
        <xsl:value-of select="msa:Name"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$History/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Name=current()/msa:Name]"/>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;    border-bottom-width: 1px;">
        <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
          <xsl:text>Date</xsl:text>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
          <xsl:text>Item</xsl:text>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
          <xsl:text>Study Point</xsl:text>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
          <xsl:text>Next Study Point</xsl:text>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
          <xsl:text>Completed</xsl:text>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
        <xsl:value-of select="name(../..)"/>
      </td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
        <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
      </td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name/@Counsel"/>
      </td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name/@NextCounsel"/>
      </td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid #000000">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name/@Completed"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works fine. But I want to exclude from the results in the `apply-templates` call:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$History/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Name=current()/msa:Name]"/>
```

... any `Item` that has a value of `Assistant` for the `Type` element.

## Update

At the moment I have changed it to use a `xsl:if` clause but it would be more elegant for the `apply-templates` call to directly omit these elements where possible:

Date
        
        
          Item
        
        
          Study Point
        
        
          Next Study Point
        
        
          Completed

```
<xsl:if test="Type != 'Assistant'">
  <tr>
    <td class="CellNormal CellBorder">
      <xsl:value-of select="name(../..)"/>
    </td>
    <td class="CellNormal CellBorder">
      <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
    </td>
    <td class="CellNormal CellBorder">
      <xsl:value-of select="Name/@Counsel"/>
    </td>
    <td class="CellNormal CellBorder">
      <xsl:value-of select="Name/@NextCounsel"/>
    </td>
    <td class="CellNormal CellBorder">
      <xsl:value-of select="Name/@Completed"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: This seems to be a trivial question: just add another predicate `[Type != 'Assistant']` to the selecting expression. Or combine the two into: `[Name=current()/msa:Name and Type != 'Assistant']`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you.